# How can I load an Image using a URL into an ImageView which is placed inside a Collapsing Toolbar Layout?

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I tried using Picasso to display the image on the background, but it doesn't seem to load the Image. It works if I try to load some image from the drawable folder. Any idea on how to fix this?

I also tried using the AsyncTask Activity where the Bitmap Image is retrieved from the URL and then given to the ImageView. It didn't seem to work as well.

And I have already given Internet Permission in my Manifest File

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="xxx">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_profile_page" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    String sessionImageLink = "xxx";
    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.with(this).load(sessionImageLink).into(imageView1);
}
```

Comment: Maybe your url link is incorrect.

Comment: @TheTechWolf Well, I checked everything other than that lol. It works fine now. Thanks!